# Linux command to find a specific line in file and add new lines below it

Tags: linux, command

I am trying to build a Linux command to find a line in file and add more lines below that line. For example search for `"Application"` in a file, then get the line where this word is and add three more lines below it.
I am currently using the absolute line number as in `"sed -i '51icolumn1, column2, column3' test.txt"` but if something change in this file I might be adding the text in a wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would

```
sed -i '/Application/a column1, column2, column3\ncolumn1, column2, column3' test.txt
```

solve your issue?

Comment: My problem is when I try to add more than one line after search for the word "Application"

Comment: Have you tried to use '\n' to separate multiple lines? (I updated my answer.)